# shopping cart suddenly stopped working c#

Tags: c#, shopping-cart, web-hosting

### the shopping cart down again, is this because the hosting company provides new temp website feature?

I do think it is hosting company play around the setting, the shopping cart is working again, and I didn't change anything....

### Is there any good reliable windows web hosting companies?

can someone please help me? The hosting company drives me mad.  My website and shopping cart were working fine couple days ago and the website is running fine in my local host, but my shopping cart has suddenly stopped working from yesterday. I think this is because of the hosting company has changed some setting, but they deny it, and say it's the problem with my code.
here's the error I got:

> [A]ShoppingCart cannot be cast to [B]ShoppingCart. Type A originates
>   from 'App_Code.ej8etxbi, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\03050970\f5f76d45\App_Code.ej8etxbi.dll'. Type B originates
>   from 'App_Code.qoxkmirc, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\03050970\f5f76d45\App_Code.qoxkmirc.dll'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: [A]ShoppingCart cannot
>   be cast to [B]ShoppingCart. Type A originates from 'App_Code.ej8etxbi,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context
>   'Default' at location
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\03050970\f5f76d45\App_Code.ej8etxbi.dll'. Type B originates
>   from 'App_Code.qoxkmirc, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\03050970\f5f76d45\App_Code.qoxkmirc.dll'.

Source Error:

```
{
// we are returning the shopping cart for the given user
return (ShoppingCart)HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPNETShoppingCart"];
}
}
```

also my website went down 11 times in less than one month, if anyone know any good, reliable windows web hosting companies, I will be appreciated if you can let me know.

Thank you

Comment: An error casting CartA to CartB will be a code issue, not a hosting issue I'm afraid.

Comment: Did you released something yesterday also check and search for ASPNETShoppingCart in your code , what are you setting with this key in your code?

Comment: @NeilThompson Type casting should through error locally too?

Comment: I don't know what I have done wrong as it is still working fine in my local host. here's some more codes for the shopping cart below:

Comment: if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPNETShoppingCart"] == null)
            {
                ShoppingCart instance = new ShoppingCart();
                instance.Items = new List<CartItem>();
                HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPNETShoppingCart"] = instance;
                return instance;
            }
            else
            {
                // we are returning the shopping cart for the given user
   return (ShoppingCart)HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPNETShoppingCart"];
            }

Comment: public class ShoppingCart {
 #region Properties
 
 public List<CartItem> Items { get; private set; }
 
 #endregion

 #region Singleton Implementation

 // Readonly properties can only be set in initialization or in a constructor
 
 // The static constructor is called as soon as the class is loaded into memory
    public static ShoppingCart Instance
    {
        get
        {

Answer (score 1):

Do you have ShoppingCart class in different  assemblies or DLL or if you have loaded same assembly multiple times then also each copy will not be considered same.

Comment: here is the only place I have declared my shopping cart in a shopping cart.cs file. sorry, this is my first time write a website with shopping cart, I don't understand what I should change? and why I can't see this error on my local host? thank you Saurabh.

Comment: Check cleaning of Temporary ASP.NET Files on server will help.

Comment: hi Saurabh, thank you for your reply. it is working again, and I didn't change anything. so odd!

Answer (score 0):

Types are per-assembly, if you have "the same" assembly loaded twice, then types in each of the assemblys are not considered to be of the same type.

So make shure all your Projects are referencing the same dll in which "ShoppingCart" is contained.

P.S Things to try clean your "Temporary ASP.NET Files" Folder and redeploy your application AFTER ensuring all references to the dll containing "ShoppingCart" are the same. Should work then.